# Find two matrices $A,B$ such that $AB=0, BA\neq 0$. What can you say about $(BA)(BA)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find two matrices $A,B$ such that $AB=0, BA\neq 0$. What can you say about $(BA)(BA)$?

I found the two matrices, but I found it to be actually not important. If associativity is true, then:

$$(BA)(BA)=B(AB)A=B(0A)=(B0)A=B(0)=0$$

Then if $AB=0, BA\neq 0$, $BABA=0$. Is that it? I don't know what else I could say about $(BA)(BA)$.

Comment: There's nothing else to say. $BABA$ is the zero matrix for the reasons you gave.

Comment: It is rather difficult to find any matrix $C$ such that $C=0, C \neq 0$. You need to visit the impoverished  land of the excluded middle.

Comment: A bit confused as to how $AB = 0$ and $\neq 0$ simultaneously.

Comment: I made a typo, corrected it now (while laughing for a bit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try A:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\ \end{array}\right)$$
and  B:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1  \\
0 & 0  \\ \end{array}\right)$$